# How to transfer textfield's label to top of prefix Icon instead of text

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, textfield, flutter-animation

In flutter's textField when we use prefixIcon and label, in focus mode label's animation transfers to the top of the text (not to the top of the icon).
I don't want to use prefix instead of prefixIcon because prefix hides when textField is not on focus mode. I need my prefix always visible.
Like these images from [material designs text fields part](https://material.io/components/text-fields#usage):
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you exact want can you explain in details as well your wanted design/UI in image

Comment: I want when user touch text field, label transfer to top of icon and icon always visible even is not in focus mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there are some fix position value,
here is my implementation,

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  bool textEditHasFocus = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        textEditHasFocus = _focusNode.hasFocus;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
      padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 40.0,
        horizontal: 20,
      ),
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: TextField(
              focusNode: _focusNode,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                // hintText: textEditHasFocus ? '' : 'Label',
                // hintStyle: TextStyle(
                //   color: Colors.grey,
                // ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            left: textEditHasFocus ? 10 : 40,
            top: textEditHasFocus ? -10 : 13,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _focusNode.requestFocus();
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Text('Label'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [material designs text fields part](https://material.io/components/text-fields) link provided I try same design and your need when you focused on `TextField` the `labelText` is display on the `prefixIcon` In lots of their is not correct solution I found

Refer `prefixIcon` Widget documentaion [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/prefixIcon.html) and see the given example

Refer `prefix` Widget documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/prefix.html)

Refer `InputDecoration` class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/InputDecoration.html)

Try below code when icon is display ouside of the TextField

```
TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.favorite,
        ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Brand Description',
        hintText: 'Brand Description Here',
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen Without focus->  [image]

Your result screen With focus->[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is one easy solution for flutter 3 plus users

```
  InputDecorator(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Select Hospital",
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
          border: OutlineInputBorder()),
      child:TextFormField(),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Focus(
  onFocusChange: (focus) {
    setState(() {
      isfocuse = focus;
    });
  },
  child: TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      //Developed by Harsh Patel
      prefix: isfocuse
          ? Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 15, 0),
              child: const Icon(Icons.favorite))
          : null,
      prefixIcon: !isfocuse
          ? GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 15, 10, 15),
                  child: const Icon(Icons.favorite)),
            )
          : null,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 15, 25, 15),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide:
            BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
      hintText: 'Enter Text',
      labelText: 'LabelText',
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Make global variable**

```
bool isfocuse = false;
```